# multiple popovers for a single field

Tags: jquery, html, popover

I have a field which fires off a couple popovers depending as the user types:

First popover is when a user enters a number, at this time the user gets a popover with a message that the field allows non number inputs

Second popover is fired when a user enters a lower case letter but can continue to enter letters

And the third popover is fired when the user reaches 10 characters

So far, I have this code:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/veogmdhs/1/)

```
<input type="text" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="manual" data-content="" name="momlastname" id="momlastname" ng-model="momlastname" />

(function () {

    function firstCapital(word) {
        return /^[A-Z]/.test(word);
    };


    function NumberOnly(e) {
        var inp = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
        if (/[0-9]/.test(inp)) return true;
        else return false;
    };

    $('#momlastname').keypress(function (f) {

        switch ($(this).val().length) {
            case 1:
                message = "Lower letter";
                break;
            case 10:
                message = "10 characters have been reached";
                break;
        }

        if (NumberOnly(f)) {
            f.preventDefault();
            $('#momlastname').popover({
                trigger: 'manual',
                content: function () {
                    return "Enter text only.  Numbers cannot be entered.";
                }
            });
            $('#momlastname').popover('show');
            $('#momlastname').addClass('error');

        } else if ($(this).val().length == 1 && !firstCapital($(this).val())) {
            $('#momlastname').popover({
                trigger: 'manual',
                content: function () {
                    return message;
                }
            });
            $('#momlastname').popover('show');
            $('#momlastname').addClass('error');
        } else if ($(this).val().length == 70) {
            $('#momlastname').popover({
                trigger: 'manual',
                content: function () {
                    return message;
                }
            });
            $('#momlastname').popover('show');
            $('#momlastname').addClass('error');
        } else {
            $('#momlastname').popover('hide');
            $('#momlastname').removeClass('error');
        }

    });

});
```

Right now, the popovers are not working but when I comment out the others, it seems to work but I need to have all 3 working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `else if`, so only the first condition met will be executed. Try taking out `else` and move your error clearing above your checks.